# How do I open files that are not located inside wine's virtual C drive?

Tags: wine

I am running winamp using wine. When I am choosing music to open in winamp I can only browse inside wine's C drive but I have all my music on a separate partition. I want to be able to play the music from that partition instead of having to copy it into a folder in wine's virtual C drive.

Comment: in several applications i can break out of wine's C drive, never used winamp though...it might be winamp specific

Answer (score 6):

From inside Winamp and other applications running within Wine then you should be able to navigate to the **'Z'** drive to access your Ubuntu filesystem.

Comment: The partition that i have my music on is not accessible through the Z drive. I got it working using Roland Taylors idea. thanks though

Comment: It should be, Z is mapped to /, which means if you can browse it on your system somewhere then it's in there. Most likely you want /media/(weird string of letters), which is where the system mounts it after you open it initially on the desktop (eg by clicking places->300 gb disk)

Comment: While using wine drives is fine for some of us (like me) some people don't understand the concept - wine and linux appear to be using different manners of reaching files, plus to a new user /media/blablabla sounds like ςηατ τηε ηελλ διδ υοθ σαυ???

Answer (score 2):

You can do what fluteflute said, or put a link into your `~/Music` folder or wine C:\ drive (type `ln -s /path/to/partition ~/.wine/pathtocdrive` in a terminal and press enter).